# Django view variables

Tags: django, view

I'm trying create a value from two user given variables in my detail view template. I've tried using jinja to do math inside of the HTML but then found that the preferred way is to create variables inside of the apps views.py file. I've found a few conflicting ways Here's what I have currently:

```
def meter_variables(request):
    GvData.incoming_meter_daily_total = (GvData.incoming_meter_1_close - GvData.incoming_meter_1_open)
    + (GvData.incoming_meter_2_close - GvData.incoming_meter_2_close)

    return render(request, 'geneva/geneva_record.html',
                  {'incoming_meter_daily_total': GvData.incoming_meter_daily_total})
```

in my html I have:

```
<td><input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Daily Total"

value="{{ incoming_meter_daily_total }}"/>
                            </td>
```

It provides no value. I think I'm accessing the values from the model object incorrectly but I'm not sure how exactly.

My class in models.py is very long but all fields are a variation on:

```
class GvData(models.Model):
    gv_01_open_stock = models.FloatField(default=0)
    gv_02_open_stock = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

My views have been created with class views:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'geneva/index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return GvData.objects.all()


class RecordView(generic.DetailView):
    model = GvData
    template_name = 'geneva/geneva_record.html'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sending the data from your view to the template as-is, you don't need to add the "object" in `value="{{ object.incoming_meter_daily_total }}"`

In your view, you're assigning the value to this key: `incoming_meter_daily_total`
So this is the exact variable that you need to use in your template

```
value="{{ incoming_meter_daily_total }}"
```

You're getting a query set from your model. And by looking at the code, you're trying to get the values directly from this query set. Django fails silently on templates, with the purpose of not breaking the whole page. Access the data from one of the elements of this query set (using `[0]` or the value desired) or loop through the query set.

Comment: I removed the object. from the incoming_meter_daily_total. It's still not providing a value. The placeholder value is being displayed, updated my code above to relfect it.

Comment: Are you accessing the data in the models like this? If that's the case, I'm not seeing the object created from the model class, also not getting the record entry in particular that has the data you want to work with. Do you do this in any other place in your views code?

Comment: I've added how my views are composed in the above code. I know I've got some kind of mismatch I just can't figure it out. I've tried adding similar code to the detail view function with no success.  Thank you for your time, it's appreciated.